# RegEx: Checking if string contains non whitelisted characters

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to check if a string contains characters that are not in whitelist, if that is indeed true, the string must be discarded.

The whitelist is currently `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!?.,` and possibly others.

It is very important for me to load the whitelist from a string (like the one provided), because I might need to expand the whitelist later.

Comment: If I understand RegEx correctly that would give me a list of the matching characters inside the string. Then I would need to compare the lengths of the original list of characters and the new list and if not matching then I'd need to discard. This works, but is probably too convoluted and it's likely that there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. Just check to see if any of the characters are not in the whitelist:

```
whitelist_set = set(whitelist)
if any(c not in whitelist_set for c in my_string):
#discard
```

As @jpp mentioned in the comments, it's more efficient to first convert the whitelist to a `set` because lookups will be `O(1)` rather than `O(n)` for `list`.

Comment: To make this efficient, you can convert `whitelist` to `set` beforehand.

Comment: @jpp does it have to be beforehand? Won't doing it inside the generator (see edit) be sufficient?

Comment: I think this may be inefficient as the set will be recalculated for every iteration within the generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.translate` to delete the characters in the whitelist and then test if you have any characters left:

```
>>> wl='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!?.,'
>>> tbl=str.maketrans({}.fromkeys(wl))
>>> tst=tgt.translate(tbl)
# If tst, there are non whitelist characters...
```

That is the Python 3 version of translate. Python 2 would be:

```
>>> tgt.translate(None, wl)
# same test...
```

You can also use set arithmetic:

```
>>> if(set(tgt)-set(wl)): #discard...
```

If you want to use a regex:

```
>>> re.search(r'[^'+wl+']',tgt)
```